# Corba - are server-side methods possible?

Tags: java, corba

Is it possible to have methods that access and change variables on the server-side of a corba object?

If so, how does one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have methods that access and change variables on the server-side of a corba object?

[CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba):

> CORBA enables separate pieces of software written in different languages and running on **different computers** to work with each other like a single application or set of services. More specifically, CORBA is a mechanism in software for normalizing the method-call semantics between application objects residing either in the same address space (application) or remote address space (same host, or remote host on a network).

So, yes  it is possible.

> If so, how does one do it?

The official [tutorial](http://v1.dione.zcu.cz/java/docs/jdk1.3/docs/guide/idl/jidlExample.html) provides explanations and `Hello world` code example.

Answer (score 2):

CORBA objects are accessed via their interface, described in [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMG_IDL).

See the [OMG tutorial](http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/omg_idl.htm).

You may add a method into the object interface to update a *'variable'*, server-side but the method should have a meaning, a semantic which is more significant than *updating a variable*.

From an OMG example:

```
interface salestax  {

     float  calculate_tax ( in float taxable_amount );
}
```

We may add a method to set a server-side *variable*:

```
interface salestax  {

     float  calculate_tax ( in float taxable_amount );

     void   setVariable( in string name, in long value );
}
```

We have to modify the implementation.